# android I can't run my application on Galaxy Core Plus Phone (SM-G350M)

Tags: android

I'm working with Eclipse Version 4.2.2, ADT Version 23.0.2.1259578, Android Development Toolkit Version: 23.0.4.1468518, Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Google USB Driver was installed

I donwload from Samsung site, Kies3 Software, and Works fine , I can see the Phone device driver on the explorer

I Installed SDK Samsung with this steps ...
Windows->Android SDK Manager->Tools TAB-> Manage Add-On Sites->User Defined Sites -> Click on New botton and put this..
http://developer.samsung.com/sdk-manager/repository/Samsung-SDK.xml

When I want to install the 15 Samsung packages I have gotten this message ....This package depends on 'Missing SDK Platform Android, API 21'

On Android Device  Chooser I can't see my Phone device, any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Why would you see an iphone device in an android device chooser?  AN iphone isn't an android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is kind of off-topic, but:
if you get the error 'Missing SDK Platform Android, API 21' just install the newest SDK via SDK-Manager

...uh yeah I oversaw this... what are you trying installing an android app on an iPhone??????????

[image]

Comment: My own application made on Eclipse

Comment: I can't see the API 21 on the list Packages

Comment: iPhone? ... no on Galaxy Core Plus Phone

Comment: see your question: "On Android Device Chooser I can't see my IPhone device, any ideas?"

Comment: you need the SDK build-tools v 21 see the screenshot

Comment: Yes, the three options I have ... but the last two options I don't have the same REV .. I have 20

Comment: ... maybe a problem with eclipse don't know exactly, I would advice you migrating your project to Android Studio https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html instead of using the Eclipse IDE

Comment: .... or if you want to stay with eclipse, you might want to checkout if there is an update available for the ADT plugin, that might be the reason why you dont see the latest SDK

Comment: Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: peer not authenticated

Comment: I still with the problem ... I can't debug on Galaxy Device Phone!

Comment: When I want to run the aplication, I have gotten the message .... " No compatible targets were found, do you wish to add a new android virtual?.

Comment: I have on AndroidManifest ... android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"  Maybe minSdkVersion is't correct to the Device with Android 4.3 version

Comment: you need to install the the drivers, install the Google USB Driver in the SDK manager, and also install the samsung drivers: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2645355

Comment: All them ... was install Google USB Drive has the Rev 11 and I can see 15 packages installed all the with the API = 21

Comment: I installed Kies 3 versión 3.2.14113_3

Comment: run cmd and call "adb devices", if you can't see your phone your drivers are not installed correctly

Comment: The list of devices it's empty .... I have another Device, it's a Motorola XT621 with 2.3.6 Versión Android .... in this Device I can run the application ... why I can't see the device on the List od devices when run the abd devices ?

Comment: I still think it is a driver issue, search for the device specific drivers via google (not just the general samsung usb drivers) maybe you also need to reboot after installing the device specific drivers in order to see the device

Comment: btw. have you activated development options and usb-debugging on your device?

Comment: try restarting adb: first -> $ adb kill-server then -> $ adb start-server

Comment: if it does not help try following these steps: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/61992 but I am pretty sure it is an issue with your drivers and not related to any android or adb stuff

Comment: Nothig ...... after adb start-server command, when the Motorola device it's connected with at USB, it's view on the List of devices ... but when the Samsung Device it's connected ... the list it's empty

Comment: another prove that you have an issue with the drivers search on google "devicename adb driver" or something like that, and make sure you unistall your old drivers, reboot your system, and maybe also run ccleaner or an equivalent tool before installing the new drivers